# Accordion control of Bootstrap not working corretly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Live version here:
http://www.bootply.com/7aYZsAKgSy

I have two of these on my page that want them to collapse or expand **independent of each other** , I do not want one of them to have affect on status of other ones.

So I have something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#PANEL1">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
                        PANEL 1
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="PANEL1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div>
                THERE IS A FORM HERE THAT IS THE STUFF IN THIS PANEL
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and then one more under it, very similar copy paste, just the ID of inner DIV is different:

I have two of these on my page that want them to collapse or expand **independent of each other** , I do not want one of them to have affect on status of other ones.

So I have something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#PANEL2">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
                        PANEL 1
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="PANEL2" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div>
                THERE IS another FORM HERE THAT IS THE STUFF IN THIS PANEL
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and then my JavaScript that is this:

```
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    $(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-chevron-up").removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-up").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-down");
}).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
    $(this).parent().find(".glyphicon-chevron-down").removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-down").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-up");
});
```

So sometimes it works, sometimes it does not. When both of them are open and I first close the second one, it also closes the first one.

Comment: If these are two separate accordions on the same page you should give them different IDs.

Comment: I think you can just remove the `data-parent` attribute. I think it's purpose is to close all the other collapsibles which is what you don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
http://www.bootply.com/MiQbLj7uIA
```

I just changed the id of the second accordion and its data-parent value.

Comment: +1 This is correct if the OP wants two accordions on the page. But I don't know if he wants that or just one accordion that expands sections independent of each other. If he wants the latter he can just remove the `data-parent` attribute altogether.

Comment: @ValterJunior I think it is working fine now. Thank you.

Comment: @Andrew : I am eventually going to have eight of these on my page, each should open/close independently of other ones. Do you think Valter's code will have an issue?

Comment: @Bohn There won't be any issue with Valter's code. But you might have unnecessary code if you just want to have 8 opening and closing panels. You can remove all the `id="accordion"` and `id="accordion2"` and `data-parent="accordion"` and `data-parent="accordion2"`  and it will work the same.